# Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'parentProjectGuid')

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

Cannot add the existing Solution file or New solution file in Vs Code. Using Solution Explorer Extension.

I have tried reinstalling Vs Code / Solution Explorer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When I first tried it with the help of [README File](https://github.com/fernandoescolar/vscode-solution-explorer#open-solutions), I got same issue you have. Here is what I do to make it running:

1. First make sure you have already installed the .NET SDK and C# extension.
2. Open the project file in the VS Code's Explorer:
   [image]
3. Now you can open the solution in the Solution Explorer:
   [image]